# Other user doesn't see Ruby installed with rbenv

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, rbenv

I have installed Ruby on my Ubuntu 14.04 server under the root account with rbenv.

```
root@droplet:~# ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i686-linux]
```

But if I log in under another user I get this message after the same command:

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby
 * ruby1.8
```

Why doesn't another user see the Ruby installation? And how can I fix it?

I'm a complete newbie to it and I may have missed something important. So tell me if you want me to provide any other info on this matter.

Comment: I guessed in my answer at what problem you're having. To confirm, what do `which rbenv` and `which ruby` say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install Ruby with rbenv so that all users on a machine can use it, you need to

- install rbenv in a public place, e.g. `/usr/local/rbenv`
- set up rbenv for each user in a shell startup file, e.g. `/etc/profile`:

  ```
  export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
  export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
  ```

[A blog post by Blake Williams gives details.](http://blakewilliams.me/posts/system-wide-rbenv-install/)

Answer (score -1):

I use `rvm` and not `rbenv` so I'm not familiar with `rbenv`.  However, I do know from the readme (https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#locating-the-ruby-installation) that, like rvm, it makes use of the shell to manage the various rubies.

Check out the "Basic GitHub Checkout" section of that readme. It's possible you can get it working on additional users by performing steps 2 to 4:

> Add `~/.rbenv/bin` to your `$PATH` for access to the rbenv command-line
>   utility.
>
> ```
> $ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> Ubuntu Desktop note: Modify your `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`.
>
> Zsh note: Modify your `~/.zshrc` file instead of `~/.bash_profile`.
>
> Run `~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init` for shell-specific instructions on how to
>   initialize rbenv to enable shims and autocompletion.
>
> Restart your shell so that `PATH` changes take effect. (Opening a new
>   terminal tab will usually do it.) Now check if rbenv was set up:
>
> ```
> $ type rbenv
> #=> "rbenv is a function"
> ```

Comment: That's strange! On my systems the `rbenv` command is never a function, but a shim file in `.../rbenv/bin`.